# Single Interface for multiple DAL

Tags: c#, class, oop, interface, object-oriented-analysis

I do have different Data Access Layers for MS Access, MS SQL and Oracle. How I can use single interface to insert data into different databases.

Single interface for different classes - is it possible ? How ? What is the name of this pattern in OOP?

It would be very helpful if someone give example in c#.

Comment: A single interface is possible and you'd want to look into the factory method pattern

Comment: You have to understand the layer in the Data Access  Class.  I would look at the c# source code at msdn : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: You'd (ideally) want to have created the data access interfaces first, then write the classes for each of the database providers you mention to conform to the interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of an interface IS to enable you what you are asking. Yes, it’s possible to have single interface for multiple classes. The pattern you are looking for is **Repository Pattern**.

> A Repository mediates between the domain and data mapping layers, acting like an in-memory domain object collection. Client objects construct query specifications declaratively and submit them to Repository for satisfaction. Objects can be added to and removed from the Repository, as they can from a simple collection of objects, and the mapping code encapsulated by the Repository will carry out the appropriate operations behind the scenes

Writing example of Repository Pattern is not possible without turning this post into a whole blog post and I would certainly refrain from that since there are many very helpful articles out there. Here are a couple of them:

https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/dhananjay_kumar/posts/how-to-implement-the-repository-pattern-in-asp-net-mvc-application

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526874/Repository-pattern-done-right

Hope this helps!

Comment: Repository pattern is the same as Factory method pattern correct ?

Comment: Nop. they are not same. Check this post for reference. http://www.dotnetfunda.com/interviews/show/5515/what-is-the-difference-between-factory-pattern-and-repository-pattern You can explore more on internet to understand more about it.